# how to send a predefined path to a local planner?

Tags: navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,

I am facing a situation.

I am recently developing a trajectory planner for research purposes. I have written the trajectory planner in a local planner, which has adhered to the local_planner interface set in nav_core.

In order to test and improve this trajectory planner, I should feed a complex enough path (curve path for example) into the trajectory planner and analyse the generated output trajectory commands. Now I can do so by setting a goal pose on Rviz and using one of the global planners. But this does not always generate exactly the same path every time.

So I wish to send a predefined complex path (or a vector of PoseStamped) to the trajectory planner directly (like using: rostopic pub), or reproduce the same complex path on Rviz feeding to the trajectory planner.

Do you have any ideas how to do so or even better methods?

Thanks very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222051/how-to-send-a-predefined-path-to-a-local-planner?/) by [Li Xie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25262/li-xie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-12-06

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-12**:
did you figure this out? if so, do you have any sample code that you can share? Thank you.

**Comment by [Li Xie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25262/li-xie/) on 2018-06-12**:
No, I did not. Although the comments below are very smart and helpful, I did not have enough time to implement that back then. I ended up with a compromised test plan (mostly focused on only testing simple paths, instead of complex paths)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the best way is to write your own global planner plugin, which adheres to the respective interface there.
However, this then does nothing when receiving the usual `move_base` goals.

Rather, you add whatever ROS concept you want (subscriber, service server, action server) to this global planner plugin for retrieving the path from wherever you want (publisher, service client, action client) and pass it down the chain.

Then, you can use the full move_base structure and can have deterministic global plans...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Li Xie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25262/li-xie/) on 2015-12-14**:
This does sound a valid idea. I think it is not difficult create the proposed global planner plugin. The more detail how to achieve retrieve the path, either by feeding the same array of vectors or built-in array of vector in the global planner, is to be determined based on global planner architectu

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path generated by the standard `move_base` mechanics is stored in a topic (I think it's called just `path`) composed of an array of vectors. My point is, those vectors are the same kind of vectors that describe the actual pose of the robot, so maybe you can build a node that retrieves the pose of the robot (taken from the odometry or whichever mechanism you're using for the localization) while you move manually your robot in the trajectory that suits your purposes.

That way you'll have an array of vectors describing the path you just made with your robot, which with minor adjustments you can publish into the `path` topic of `move_base`.

I don't know how complex this could be, but if it isn't possible the easy way is record a `bag file` of a path generated from `move_base` that seems good to you, and replay it anytime you want.

---

Originally posted by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) with karma: 258 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-12-10**:
I strongly disagree. The `path` topic is **published** from the [`global_planner`](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner), so you cannot send a `path` to `move_base`. There is no subscriber...

**Comment by [Li Xie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25262/li-xie/) on 2015-12-14**:
thanks very much for your answer. I will later take a deeper look into the path topic to see if there were a way to implement.